# Getting a shape mismatch error message when trying to plot a stacked barchart

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I am trying to create a stacked barchart from my data and keep getting an error message

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single
>   shape

This is what the relevant code I have written:

```
num = list(yearly_posts.index)
barWidth = 0.50
plt.bar(num,yearly_status.values, color='#b5ffb9',edgecolor='white',width=barWidth)
plt.bar(num,yearly_posts.values, color='#f9bc86',edgecolor='white',width=barWidth)
```

and this is a sample of my data

```
#yearly_status table
year
2009     85
2010     86
2011    188
2012    274
2013    240
2014    171
2015    132
2016     22
2017     18
2018     13
dtype: int64

#yearly_posts table
year
2009     8
2010    19
2013    19
2014    40
2015    13
2016    20
2017    27
2018    17
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `yearly_status.values` and `yearly_posts.values` have different sizes, yet you only use one `num` (with the size of `yearly_posts`). You should probably change the `num` in your first `plt.bar` call to something like `list(yearly_status.index)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that both your dataframes has unequal no. of entries which is why the `num` was different for both. The solution is to use different indexes for both as `num1` and `num2`. Additionally, you will have to flatten your values 2d array into a 1-d array as `yearly_status.values.flatten()`

```
num1 = list(yearly_status.index)
num2 = list(yearly_posts.index)
barWidth = 0.50
plt.bar(num1, yearly_status.values.flatten(), color='#b5ffb9',edgecolor='white',width=barWidth)
plt.bar(num2, yearly_posts.values.flatten(), color='#f9bc86',edgecolor='white',width=barWidth)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that the length of both list objects are equal and still getting a `shape mismatch` error. You can convert the list object to a numpy array before plotting.

```
import numpy as np
numpyObject = np.array(listObject)
```